# C# project templates don't show up in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#

I just started learning C#. I downloaded Visual Studio 2022, chose C# in the options and installed it, but C# does not appear in the templates list.

[image]

When installing VS, I chose developing games with Unity along with C#.

I'm not using any pirated licensing, all my licenses are original. I also tried the repair option, it still didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you create a blank solution using that "Blank Solution" template and then a C# project inside?

Comment: I created an empty project, but I still don't understand, it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried selecting C# instead of "All languages"? Does it appear in the drop-down list?

Comment: Open _Visual Studio Installer_. Click _Modify_. On _Workloads_ tab, select _.NET Desktop Development_ and _Game Development With Unity_  workloads. Then,  click _Individual Components_ and select any desired individual components to install.

Comment: Look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: By the way, the OP selected .NET and Unity when installing. Said clearly in the question.